# how to update model in yii using specific attributes?

Tags: php, yii, attributes, updatemodel

I have a model called `DisnotificationUpdate`. Primary key in the table is `id`.

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'notifi_id' => 'Notifi',
            'view' => 'View',
            'userid' => 'Userid',
        );
    }
```

I want to update the table using `userid` attribute (eg: `update DisnotificationUpdate set view='1' where userid='c01'`) How can I do this in yii?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DisnotificationUpdate::model()->updateAll(array('view'=>1),'userid=:uid',array(':uid'=>$uid));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $models = DisnotificationUpdate::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('userid'=>'c01'));
  foreach($models as $model){
      $model->view = '1';
      $model->save();
  }
```

Or

```
  $sql = "UPDATE disnotificationupdate set view='1' where userid='c01'"; 
  //assuming you table name is disnotificationupdate 
  Yii::app()->bd->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Comment: Your first answer is not updating every  rows with userid='c01'.Second answer is correct.